# Can this exponential be complex valued?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

My complex analysis is very sketchy, and I am a little stumped by the following - although it seems incredibly innocuous.

For $t\in\mathbb R$ and a fixed parameter $\alpha\in\mathbb R/\{0\}$ does it ever follow, or make sense to say, that $e^{-\alpha t}\in\mathbb C$?

My initial thought is that no, this can't be the case, since we have the image of real number under the exponential. However, I am looking at a problem which has that,

$$\langle e^{-\alpha t}x,y\rangle_{\mathcal H}=e^{-\alpha t}\langle x,y\rangle_{\mathcal H}=\langle x,e^{\alpha t}y\rangle_{\mathcal H},$$

where $x,y\in\mathcal H$, a Hilbert space, over the field $\mathbb K\in\{\mathbb R,\mathbb C\}$.

The only way that I can see that this would make sense would be if $e^{-\alpha t}\in\mathbb C$, but can this be justified with the information given?

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange ! Mathematically , $e^{-\alpha t}\in \mathbb C$ is correct because $\mathbb R$ is a subset of $\mathbb C$ (in plain text : a real number is also a complex number). But you surely want to  know whether your expression is always real - yes, it is

Comment: $e^{-\alpha t} \in \mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{C} $.

Comment: I should have emphasised, can it be that $e^{-\alpha t}\in\mathbb C/\mathbb R$? That is, *purely* complex? Because otherwise, if it is not purely complex, then manipulating the inner product as highlighted above wouldn't follow? Since $e^{-\alpha t}\in\mathbb R$ would coincide with it's complex conjugate and not be $e^{\alpha t}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think "purely complex number" is a standard terminology (as opposed to "purely imaginary"). What you could say is "nonreal complex number".

Anyway, your computation is incorrect. If $\alpha,t$ are real (and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is an inner product), then $\langle e^{-\alpha t}x,y\rangle=\langle x,e^{-\alpha t}y\rangle$. What you wrote would be correct only if $\lvert e^{-\alpha t}\rvert=1$, or equivalently, if  $\alpha t$ is purely imaginary --- only in this case it is true that $(e^{-\alpha t})^{-1}=\overline{e^{-\alpha t}}$.

My guess is that wherever you are taking this from, there's a missing imaginary unit, i.e., it should be $\langle e^{-\alpha ti}x,y\rangle=\langle x,e^{\alpha t i}y\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on terminology there.

Answer (score 0):

Every real number is also a complex number. So, for every real value of $x$, the value $e^x$ is a complex number. Because it is a real number, and all real numbers are complex.